# How can I code a image format like jfif or How can I find the background code of jfif

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, photoshop, jfif

How can I code a image format like jfif or How can I find the background code of jfif format. On web I only find informations about how jfif works but where is the codes that were doing all these steps?

Comment: show us some code

Comment: I'm asking to how can I find them, hello?

Comment: http://www.ijg.org/files/ which has latest code and some good PDFs too.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only source that I know of that explains how to program a JPEG Encoder/Decoder.

[https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)